# How to find a list of all unmanaged DLLs loadad by my managed .net application

Tags: .net, dll, unmanaged

My managed .net application uses third party .net  libraries, which use (via PInvoke) unmanaged dlls. I would like to find out, which dlls are loaded. I tried to use "Process Explorer" and "Dependency Walker", but I can only see the managed DLLs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Any debugger could do this (`windbg` for example) - but since it's a good chance you're packing Visual Studio I'll talk about how to do it in that*

Attach the Visual Studio debugger to the application, remembering to select only the Native debugger as follows:

[image: How to set debugger type to Native]

Once you're attach, hit Debug -> Break and then press `[CTRL] + [ALT] + [U]` to bring up the Modules window (it's on the menu somewhere but I can't find it!) - here's an example shot from the Samsung Kies application my desktop (which uses WPF):

[image: The modules list]

In my case I enabled the Managed debugger too, and moved the process name to the start of the columns list for the purposes of that screenshot.

If the process name has `: Native` after it, then it's an unmanaged DLL (well, it could also be mixed-mode I suppose).

Note that *all* processes in Windows will *always* have a good long list of unmanaged DLLs loaded; because Windows is unmanaged at it's heart and is the ultimate host of the application.

But certainly you can use this list as a starting point and filter down from there.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactely what I needed.